# How to color the unit test output in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have some unit tests which output to the "Standard Output" view in Visual Studio.

I'd like to color some lines according to the output's validity.

How can that be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any built in way to colour the output (allthough not tested, I am not even sure if the methods used for the normal Window's command prompt work). However this seems promising:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496

> VSColorOutput can change the color of a line emitted to the output window based on specified rules. The rules consist of regular expressions. Rules map to classifications which in turn map to colors. (More information)